# Arch Linux crashing (brutal shutdown) when opening/closing windows and logging in while on battery

Tags: laptop, arch-linux, battery, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

The title sums it up pretty well. My computer has been shutting down during certain activities when on battery after I install Artix Linux, and still does it after I uninstalled that and installed Arch. I have been looking for a fix, but can't find anything.

It tends to shut down during login (not as often) or when opening and closing my web browser (Brave) (more often), but very rarely also when opening a window, but never when I just leave it alone. When it crashes after closing the web browser, there is a perceivable moment before it actually crashes, so it's not immediate as far as I can tell. This never happens on AC no matter what I do.

I am currently using Arch Linux with kernel 5.13.13-arch1-1. I did not have this problem on Windows 10. My computer is an MSI GF65 Thin 9SD.

Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Output of inxi:

```
System:    Host: beren Kernel: 5.13.13-arch1-1 x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.5 Distro: Arch Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GF65 Thin 9SD v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16W1 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: E16W1IMS.10B 
           date: 05/19/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 40.7 Wh (100.0%) condition: 40.7/51.3 Wh (79.3%) 
CPU:       Info: 6-Core Intel Core i7-9750H [MT MCP] speed: 4210 MHz min/max: 800/4500 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 470.63.01 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia resolution: 1: 1600x900~60Hz 
           2: 1920x1080~120Hz 
           Message: Unable to show advanced data. Required tool glxinfo missing. 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 85.87 GiB (18.0%) 
Info:      Processes: 289 Uptime: 26m Memory: 15.47 GiB used: 1.77 GiB (11.4%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.06 
[thomasv@beren log]$ sudo inxi -b
System:    Host: beren Kernel: 5.13.13-arch1-1 x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.5 Distro: Arch Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GF65 Thin 9SD v: REV:1.0 serial: 9S716W112004ZJA000853 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16W1 v: REV:1.0 serial: BSS-0123456789 UEFI: American Megatrends v: E16W1IMS.10B 
           date: 05/19/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 40.7 Wh (100.0%) condition: 40.7/51.3 Wh (79.3%) 
CPU:       Info: 6-Core Intel Core i7-9750H [MT MCP] speed: 4399 MHz min/max: 800/4500 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 470.63.01 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia resolution: 1: 1600x900~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~120Hz 
           Message: Unable to show advanced data. Required tool glxinfo missing. 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 72.29 GiB (15.2%) 
Info:      Processes: 293 Uptime: 27m Memory: 15.47 GiB used: 1.79 GiB (11.6%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.06
```

Thank you!

Comment: If it happens on battery but never AC then you may need to replace the battery.

Comment: @Mokubai I don't think that that's the problem, since it never did that on Windows. Is there any way I can check without installing Windows again? The battery is a bit less than a year and a half old.

Comment: Sudden unexpected shutdowns are more often than not power supply issues and batteries do suddenly go bad. You battery has lost 20% of its life in the duration you have been using it which suggests reasonably good use. Batteries do tend to go bad very suddenly and failure under sudden load changes, such as when the machine has finished booting, is waiting for input, then back to loading stuff again, is a symptom. Batteries can go bad at any time and it being okay in the past is not a sign that it is okay now. https://www.google.com/search?&q=battery+whiskers

Comment: Windows may also have better power management for your graphics card than Linux, I've seen a lot of pages that suggest that Linux support for mixed integrated + dedicated GPU systems is, at best, "interesting". It may well be that Linux is leaving the Nvidia GPU in a high power mode rather than using your Intel GPU and putting more strain on the battery and provoking the failure.